# Is it possible to show a warning when laptop battery gets down to 20% remaining battery life?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I have a Dell laptop running Windows 7. When running on battery power, an alert pops up when the battery goes below 7% remaining battery life. Within 5 minutes of hitting 7% it goes into sleep mode. I understand my battery is having a problem and it does not last for even 1 minute after reaching 7% remaining battery life.

I want Windows to show an alert when it reaches 20% remaining battery life so that I will have enough time to plugin my laptop to AC power.

Can any body please tell me if it is possible to have Windows show a warning when battery reaches 20% battery life remaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In windows 7 go into the control panel, search for "power" and click `edit power plan` under Power Options. Then click `Change advanced power settings` You can then scroll down and change all the battery percentages to your desired settings as well as actions taken when these levels are reached.

Comment: Thanks for answering,+1.I have set at 19% but still it alerts only at 5%

Comment: I would verify the setting is still set to 19%. Other than that I would try rebooting windows. Another thing to check would be the systems CMOS/Bios settings to see if there are any settings there to try. Often times CMOS/Bios has a battery conditioning option which could also help you with your battery issue.